# Windows C/C++ Crypto API Examples and tips

Tags: c++, c, windows, cryptoapi, mscapi

I'm asking this question because I've spent the best part of a day trawling through msdn docs and other opaque sources for simple straightforward guidelines on how to get started with the Windows C/C++ Crypto API.

What I'd like to see is some example code, typical include paths, linking guidelines, etc, anything useful really. I know this is an imprecise question but I reckon imprecise answers are better none at all.

I'll get the ball rolling with my own meager findings...

Comment: Do you mean classic CryptoAPI as in Win2k and XP, or CNG ("CryptoAPI Next Generation") as in Vista and Win7? The two are not the same.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I mean the CryptoAPI but I'm compiling on a Windows 7 system.

Comment: It would be better to use CNG

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's a bunch of examples I've found....

- [Example C Program: Listing the Certificates in a Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Example C Program: Using CryptAcquireContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Example C Program: Enumerating CSP Providers and Provider Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382359%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Example C Code for Opening Certificate Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Example C Program: Sending and Receiving a Signed and Encrypted Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Example C Program: Signing a Hash and Verifying the Hash Signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

MSDN has these examples scattered around the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380252.aspx)

This [website](http://web.archive.org/web/20170212022801/https://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/) provides a good overview of the concepts along with cross-platform examples

Comment: You can just merge your two answers.

Comment: Wow, and not an example that simply encrypts data.

Answer (score 18):

The msdn docs are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380252.aspx

This is the main include file: `#include <wincrypt.h>`

The cryptography bits are included as part of the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924), which is typically installed in `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\SDKVERSION` (e.g., `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A`). The headers are typically in `%WINDOWSSDK%\Include`, and the related libraries are in `%WINDOWSSDK%\Lib`.

You must link to the cryptography libraries explicitly. Assuming you're in Visual Studio, you can add the reference by right clicking on the C++ project, choosing properties, and selecting Configuration Properties -> Linker on the treeview at left. You can then specify `crypt32.lib` in the input field on the right.

Alternately, (assuming you're using msvc++) add

```
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
```

to your source.

Comment: I significantly revised and expanded this answer. Please check to ensure you think the changes are useful :)

Comment: Ah!, thanks, I would never have thought of using the #pragma directive.

Comment: I was using #include <wincrypt.h> and #include <cryptdlg.h> in my VC++2017 project and I got error "LNK2019" when callling their api functions. Addding the line #pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib") solved it! Thanks :D

Comment: Wow, thanks, I wonder why this is not part of any MSDN guide.

Answer (score 6):

There is also a lengthy example **"[Encryption using the Win32 Crypto API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11578/Encryption-using-the-Win32-Crypto-API)"** over at the Code Project.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for several hours, I found this one here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/get-information-authenticode-signed-executables

It's detailed, and it works.